# Bootstrap 4 Collapsed Navbar - Can't align non-collapsible items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, inline

I'm working on a collapsible navbar/toggle, but I can't get the "non-collapsible" items to display inline when the navbar is toggled.

Here is the template code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light sticky-top">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home">Logo</span></a>

    <!-- Navbar toggler icon -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseMe">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!--  Collapsible items -->     
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapseMe">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--  Non-collapsible items -->
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Current: Non-collapsed view**

[image]

**Current: Collapsed view -- Non-collapsible items (Test & Logout) are not inline**

[image]

**Current: Collapsed menu toggle displays properly**
[image]

**This is what I want**

[image]

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: It's worth noting that some phraseologies, intended to be politenesses, are likely to be interpreted as excessive pleading. Over the course of a Stack Overflow career, that might result in more downvotes or negative reactions than would otherwise be the case from a set of succinct questions. More information [in available in this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).